# Emacs, how to toggle between words (true to false, etc...) Equivalent of toggle_words vim plugin

Tags: emacs, elisp

Thank you very much in advance.
I'd like to know if anyone knows about a lisp code that would allow to me to
toggle between a list of words when I press some keys.
For example:
true - false
yes - no
up - right - down - left - up ...

Threre is a plugin for vim that does exactly that, it's name is
toggle_words. I really miss this functionality in emacs.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [RotateText](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RotateText)